# SSRS Hiding the Group Column but not the Totals

Tags: reporting-services

I have a table on an SSRS report that has 5 groups of Payer Categories.  I can create a table that groups these Payer Categories and has a sub total row for each category.  However, I don't want to show the Grouping column but only show the subtotal row.

I tried hiding the group but then no data is shown.
Is there a way to hide the group column but still show the subtotals?
Currently, the table has these headings:

```
Group | Payer Category | Amount Collected | Charge
 G1   |    PC1         |   $xxx.xx        |  $xxx.xx
           PC2         |   $xxx.xx        |  $xxx.xx
        SubTotal       |   $xxx.xx        |  $xxx.xx
G2    |   PC4          |   $xxx.xx        |  $xxx.xx
          PC5          |   $xxx.xx        |  $xxx.xx
        SubTotal       |   $xxx.xx        |  $xxx.xx
TOTAL                  |   $xxx.xx        |  $xxx.xx
```

What I want the table to look like is this:

```
 Payer Category | Amount Collected | Charge
     PC1         |   $xxx.xx        |  $xxx.xx
     PC2         |   $xxx.xx        |  $xxx.xx
   SubTotal      |   $xxx.xx        |  $xxx.xx
    PC4          |   $xxx.xx        |  $xxx.xx
    PC5          |   $xxx.xx        |  $xxx.xx
  SubTotal       |   $xxx.xx        |  $xxx.xx
   TOTAL         |   $xxx.xx        |  $xxx.xx
```

I either need to hide the group or somehow create rows that subtotal and total the groups.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried deleting Group column?  When attempt to delete, you should get notification to either remove column only or group along with other fields attached to this group.  Choose remove column only.

Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: I tried doing that but it kept removing the group.  But I basically did the same thing only deleted the text in the column in the table then selected the column without selecting the group and was able to delete. So, I will mark your comment as the answer because that is what should have happened.